# Trying to get all matches from PHP preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to match a list of quoted strings and get each quoted substring.  PHP's `preg_match_all` validates the list of quoted strings, but the returned "$matches" does not contain all of the quoted substrings - usually it only returns the first and last.

I've tried assigning names `(?P<name>)` to the components of the expression, but that seems to only lead to duplication of the results, and I still don't receive all the quoted substrings.

Using `DEFINE` to create subroutines for the components didn't improve the results.

Below is an example of the input I'm trying to match.

```
   'abcd','efgh"ij','list,543','Brown fox.','left(paren','right)paren'
```

Below is the expression I'm using.  Please note that the strings are quoted ONLY with single quotes.

```
   /(?x)^   (\x27[^\x27]*\x27)   (,(\x27[^\x27]*\x27))*    $/
```

The call to `preg_match_all` looks like:

```
$pregex = '/(?x)^   (\x27[^\x27]*\x27)   (,(\x27[^\x27]*\x27))*    $/';
echo 'Match result: '.preg_match_all($pregex, $text_list, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)."\n";
```

After execution, $matches contains:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'abcd','efgh"ij','list,543','Brownfox.','left(paren','right)paren'
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'abcd'
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => ,'right)paren'
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'right)paren'
        )

)
```

...Which I notice as the string "Brown fox." changed to "Brownfox.", which is a problem and it doesn't list all the quoted substrings.

What I'd like to see is something like (notice there are no commas at the beginning of the returned substrings, but if they must be there, so be it):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'abcd','efgh"ij','list,543','Brownfox.','left(paren','right)paren'
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'abcd'
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'efgh”ij'
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'list,543'
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'Brown fox.'
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'left(paren'
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'right)paren'
        )

)
```

I guess my questions are:

1. Is it possible to accomplish what I want using preg_match_all?
2. If it IS possible, then what am I doing wrong or what don't I
   understand?
3. If it IS possible, then how do I accomplish the
   required parsing?

Thanks!

Comment: `$string = explode(',',$string); $string = array_map('trim',$string,array_fill(0,count($string),"'"));`

Comment: or if you want to stick with regex.. `preg_match_all("~'([^']+)'~",$string,$matches);print_r($matches);`

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give it a try!  I'm not sure what the "~" does, but I'll look it up.

Comment: it's the pattern delimiter. You used `/` in your pattern. But you can use basically anything. I personally favor `~` because reasons

Comment: Never mind - "~" is the delimiter for the expression!

Answer (score -1):

Many thanks to Crayon Violent for his help!  His expression solved my problem.

I chose the regex solution he offered as when the substrings contain one or more commas (as in `'efgh"ij','list,543','Brown fox'`), the comma within the `"list,543"` substring throws off the parsing by explode.

The original regex I had does a great job of validating the input, but it wasn't providing the array of substrings.  The regex Crayon Violent provides DOES provide the array of substrings, but doesn't validate the input, so my solution is to use both, as in:

```
$token_count = 0;

// Trim leading and trailing blanks from the input.
$trimmed_input_text = trim($text_input);

// Validate the input using preg_match
$pregex_validate = '/(?x)^ [ ]*  \(   [ ]*   (\x27[^\x27]*\x27)  (   [ ]*   ,  [ ]*   (\x27[^\x27]*\x27))*   [ ]*   \)  [ ]*   $/';
if (preg_match($pregex_validate, $trimmed_input_text)) {
   // Use preg_match_all to get the substrings in an array
   $pregex_parse = "~'([^']+)'~";
   $token_count = preg_match_all($pregex_parse, $trimmed_input_text, $matches);
}
```

The resulting `$matches` yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'abcd'
            [1] => 'efgh"ij'
            [2] => 'list,543'
            [3] => 'Brown fox.'
            [4] => 'left(paren'
            [5] => 'right)paren'
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => abcd
            [1] => efgh"ij
            [2] => list,543
            [3] => Brown fox.
            [4] => left(paren
            [5] => right)paren
        )

)
```

... which is exactly what I want!

Again, many thanks to Crayon Violent for his help!

John

Comment: Using a regex to do that is just a waste of time: `str_getcsv(trim($str), ',', "'")` does the same in one line.

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks!  And it correctly handled a string with an embedded comma!  Thanks!  In almost 20 years of PHP str_getcsv is one function I hadn't run across.